# In my Visual-force PDF Page table is not breaking properly

Tags: apex, visualforce

My requirement is table content not fit in a single page.

My code

```
 <table border="1" style="border-collapse: collapse;" width="100%">
                <caption>Schedule of Intallment(s) </caption>
                <tr>
                    <th width="10%" style="text-align:center;padding: 5px;">#</th>
                    <th width="15%" style="text-align:center;padding: 5px;">Percentage (%)</th>
                    <th width="25%" style="text-align:center;padding: 5px;">Date</th>
                       <!-- new line -->
                    <th width="25%" style="text-align:center;padding: 5px;">Description</th> 
                    <th width="25%" style="text-align:center;padding: 5px;">Amount (AED)</th>
                    <th width="25%" style="text-align:center;padding: 5px;">Total Amount</th> 
                </tr>
                <apex:repeat value="{!paymentlist[plot.id]}" var="pi">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="text-align:center;padding: 5px;">{!pi.Count}
                        </td>                
                        <td style="text-align:center;padding: 5px;">{!pi.percentage}
                        </td>
                        <td style="text-align:center;padding: 5px;">
                             <!-- new line pi.count==1 -->
                            <apex:outputText value="{0,date,dd-MMM-yyyy}" rendered="{!!pi.isLast && pi.Count==1}"> 
                                <apex:param value="{!pi.instllmentDate}" /> 
                            </apex:outputText>
                              <!-- new line -->
                              <apex:outputText value="During Construction" rendered="{!!pi.isLast && pi.Count != 1}"> 
                                
                            </apex:outputText>
                            <apex:outputText value="On Completion" rendered="{!pi.isLast}"> 
                               
                            </apex:outputText>
                            
                        </td>
                         <!-- new line -->
                         <td style="text-align:center;padding: 5px;">{!pi.Description}
                        </td>
                        <td style="text-align:right;padding: 5px;">
                            <apex:outputText value="AED{0, number, ###,##0.00}">
                                <apex:param value="{!pi.amount}"/>
                            </apex:outputText>
                            
                        </td>
                        <td style="text-align:right;padding: 5px;">
                            <apex:outputText value="AED{0, number, ###,##0.00}">
                                <apex:param value="{!pi.TotalAmount}"/>
                            </apex:outputText>
                            
                        </td>
                    </tr>            
                </apex:repeat>
                <tr>
                    <td style="padding: 5px;" colspan="4"><b>Total</b></td>
                    <td style="text-align:right;padding: 5px;"><b>
                        <apex:outputText value="AED{0, number, ###,##0.00}">
                            <apex:param value="{!plotTotal[plot.id]}"/>
                        </apex:outputText>
                        </b>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

How to make this table flexible depending upon the data?

Result what I am getting:
The Total is getting printed into the next page. I need to print it in a single page

[image]

Comment: This answer can give some inspiration - https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/342473/page-break-issue-in-visualforce-render-as-pdf

Answer (score 0):

To fit on a single page, the content must fit on a page. The outside of the page is unprintable area. Try using a smaller font or resizing the columns so that they fit on 2-3 lines instead of 4-5. If you try and force the total to be on the same page, the net result is that the last line before the total will *also* appear on the next page.

You can try to fix it with:

```
<tr style="break-before: avoid-page; page-break-before: avoid;">
```

But, as I said, if the total line would overflow, it will take the row above it to the next page as well.